# Change global style className to hash className without using css module

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, classname

I'm finding a solution that can change the following style

```
<div className='projects-main'>
    <div className='basic-projects'>
       // ...
    </div>
</div>
```

to the following hash className after output the production build

```
<div class='sd21cdce'>
    <div class='vf42dq1d'>
       // ...
    </div>
</div>
```

My project maintains all the styles in one main.scss file

```
@import "./components/header";
@import "./portfolios";
@import "./blogs";
@import "./about";
@import "./contact";
@import "./gallery";
@import "./skills";
@import "./portfolio-detail";
@import "./project";

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

// ...
```

I want to change the className without using the CSS module.

```
import styles from project.module.scss

<div className={styles.projectMain}></div>
```

Most of the solutions are using the CSS module, like the above. But the Reactjs/Nextjs project is too enormous that couldn't use the CSS module method to replace all the normal CSS methods.

And I couldn't find a possible solution on any website. Is this possible to do? Or I have to use the CSS module to achieve the hash className.

Please let me know if there are any unclear or I'm wrong with the concept.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to switch all your css to use css-modules. You can do that selectively. That's what I recommend here.

Comment: Can you specify a little more? My main target is to hash the className without using CSS-modules. If I don't use CSS-module, is there any way I can hash all the CSS? Thanks

Comment: [Disable css-modules](https://cwtuan.blogspot.com/2022/10/disable-css-module-in-nextjs-v1231-sept.html) in Next.js v12.3.1 (Sept, 2022)